# Wordpress anchor from chil pages dont working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, url, anchor

I need your expertise on a problem I encounter on wordpress:

I have a main menu that has links with anchors like:

- Custom page + #IDANCHOR

Everything works very well on the homepage and on the children's pages like :

https://nomdemonsite/pagex

But as soon as I'm on a page one level down, the links don't work as soon as they have an anchor:

https://nomdemonsite/pagex/subpage

If I remove the anchor ( #IDANCHOR) from the url the links work everywhere...

Does anyone have any idea why, please?

I tried to load all the js on the site on this page which is different since it brings up a 'portfolio'.

Here is the site in question:

on this url everything works
https://dev.cinqsixproduction.com

The problem appears here:

https://dev.cinqsixproduction.com/cases/reportages/

I tried to dig around, tried to force the bonds, but I couldn't help it.
Would you have an idea before I try to tamper with the theme code please? :)

Thank you all for your help,

Have a nice day!

gl hf !

Comment: Maybe I do not got the question. But this works fine: https://dev.cinqsixproduction.com/cases/reportages/#othercases  What exactly means "links don't work" ?

Comment: Works for me too. But in general: anchors are not sent to the server. They are handled by the browser. So you shouldn't have to do anything but putting the right anchors in the source code. It's not like any other part of the URL (domain, folders, parameters)

Comment: If you go on this page :https://dev.cinqsixproduction.com/cases/reportages/
Links in menu dont works :/ except CONTACT